# Self-designation of buddhism

Tags: language

Since Buddhism is is a western term combining Buddha with  the common "-ism" suffix, I wonder whether there is/are eastern self-designations of Buddhism as a religion. Of course there are self-designations of various schools (Theravāda, Zen, ...), Dhamma/Dharma and Sangha refer to teaching and community, but is there some overarching terminology in asia?

Comment: Buddha-dharma (some Asian countries), Buddha-sasana (Theravadan countries), Buddha-agama (some Sri Lankan). Meanings are Natural-laws/fundamentals of the Buddha, Teaching/lineage of the Buddha and Religion/Doctrine of the Buddha, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

[Vinaya Pitaka --
The Basket of the Discipline](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/index.html)

> It helps to keep in mind that the name the Buddha gave to the spiritual path he taught was "***Dhamma-vinaya***" — the Doctrine (*Dhamma*) and Discipline (*Vinaya*) — suggesting an integrated body of wisdom and ethical training. The Vinaya is thus an indispensable facet and foundation of all the Buddha's teachings, inseparable from the Dhamma, and worthy of study by all followers — lay and ordained, alike. Lay practitioners will find in the Vinaya Pitaka many valuable lessons concerning human nature, guidance on how to establish and maintain a harmonious community or organization, and many profound teachings of the Dhamma itself. But its greatest value, perhaps, lies in its power to inspire the layperson to consider the extraordinary possibilities presented by a life of true renunciation, a life lived fully in tune with the Dhamma.

Comment: Dhamma-Vinaya sounds too generic. For example, the suttas have the phrase: "tathāgatappaveditassa dhammavinayassa: teaching and training proclaimed by a Realized One". For example, DN 1 appears to refer to the dhamma-vinaya of other ascetics and brahmins.

Comment: A sutta quotes the Buddha as saying, "*imasmiṁ dhammavinaye*" which I think means, "this Dhamma-Vinaya".

Comment: yes, "this", meaning "The Buddha's"

Answer (score 3):

ChrisW's answer is great, but might not be what you're looking for (I understood your question to be about commonplace, modern terminology).

In East Asia, Buddhism is "Buddha's Teaching" or "Teaching of the Buddha" (佛教, 불교, 仏教). In South Asia, generally "Buddha Dharma," meaning basically the same thing. In Southeast Asia, some languages use a term closer to "Buddha Religion," but the meaning is similar.

Answer (score 3):

With all due consideration,

The answer is yes, there is an overarching terminology in Asia for the native designation of **Buddhism** as a religion. For ease of understanding it would be recommended to narrow down the area only to Southern Asia at first, namely to acknowledge how the question applies to the dialects of the Indian Subcontinent.

In this regard, for Nepali, Gujarati, Marathi and Kannada, the designation is **Bauddha Dharma**, for Punjabi it is **Budha Dharama**, while for Hindi **Buddh Dharm**. So, in Pali, it would be the **Buddha Dhamma**. While moving along the Asian continent, the form of the words changes, but the meaning of the expression remains basically the same.

Terminologically, defining the notion of Dhamma as a standalone word can mean the nature of things or phenomena with the sense of principle or fundamental truth that explains the essence of things or phenomena. Deontologically, Dhamma can be said to mean righteousness, morality, wholesomeness, truthfulness.

Phraseologically, Buddha Dhamma can be said to mean the philosophy, religion, or doctrine taught by the Buddha, and if an attempt at an English translation from a thoroughly doctrinal point of view is permitted, the core of the terminology would be **the truth as it was expounded by the perfectly enlightened one.**

Respectfully

Comment: the word 'dhamma' means 'support' or 'life support'. it does not really mean philosophy, religion, or doctrine. Wikipedia says: "The word dharma has roots in the Sanskrit dhr-, which means to hold or to support, and is related to Latin firmus (firm, stable). From this, it takes the meaning of "what is established or firm", and hence "law". It is derived from an older Vedic Sanskrit n-stem dharman-, with a literal meaning of "bearer, supporter"

Comment: Greetings. The notion of Dhamma was only taken into account phraseologically for the given context, so thank you for pointing out the possible need for a separate definition. It has been added to the answer and for those unfamiliar with Pali, it does offer a more thorough understanding of the terminology indeed. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Good question; for which I am unsure of a precise answer. The Pali contains phrases such as:

- Tathāgatappaveditassa dhammavinayassa: teaching and discipline proclaimed by the Realized One (Tathāgata/One Thus Gone).
- Vadi mahasamano: Doctrine of the Great Recluse.
- Buddhadhammā: Teachings of the Buddha
- Buddhavacana: Sayings/words of the Buddha
- Bhagavatā dhammaṁ: Teaching by the Blessed One

The simplest most self-explanatory self-designation is probably Buddhadhammā however the most common simple self-designation in the scriptures would be Buddhavacana.

For Westerners, my personal view is Buddhadhammā is best because it makes a person question what the term 'Dhamma' means. In other words, when the inappropriate question is often asked: "*Is Buddhism a religion or a philosophy?*", the proper answer to this question is: "*Buddhism is a dhamma*". However, to give this answer, the meaning of the word 'dharma/dhamma' must be understood.